# Print data frame assignments using addTaskCallback

Tags: r

I have a hack to print data frames when I am running code interactively and not print data frames if in a rendered document but I'd like to have this happen under the hood.

Current solution:

```r
iprint <- function(x) { # only prints when interactive & not on render
  if (interactive()) {
    print(x)
  } else {
    invisible(x)
  }
}

x <-
  mtcars |>
  iprint()
```

Attempt using task callback but not working:

```r
addTaskCallback(
  name = "head_df",
  function(...) { 
    expr <- expression(...)[[1]]
    if (expr[[1]] == "<-") {                    # if it is an assignment
      if (inherits(expr[[3]], "data.frame")) {  # and a data frame
        head(expr[[3]])                         # print the data frame
      }
    }
  }
)


head(mtcars)      # shouldn't print bc no assignment

x <- head(mtcars) # should print
```

I have more logic to make this a function that takes into account if things are interactive, to toggle the callback on/off, etc. Just trying to get the task callback to work.

Comment: Do you get `Error in expr[[1]] : object of type 'symbol' is not subsettable` for head-df?

Comment: I do . I see now that it seems to be just on the command where I create the callback; all subsequent commands don't show the error

Comment: Well, where it registers the name, it doesn't seem to 'register' the function, i.e. `x <- head(mtcars)` doesn't print, but assigns, which the task function is meant to reverse,, or perhaps reveal, even as assigning... Better thinkers will come along and I'll follow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A nifty idea! Here's a way to do it that takes advantage of the other arguments to the task callback:

```
addTaskCallback(
    name = "head_df",
    function(expr, result, complete, printed, ...) { 
      if (!printed && inherits(result, "data.frame")) {
          print(head(result))
      }
      TRUE
    }
  )
```

This basically says "if the result of a task is a data frame, but the data frame wouldn't be printed, print it". That'll cover assignment as well as other operations that ordinarily wouldn't print results.

If you really want to do this *just* for assignment, you might find `deparse` helpful so you can compare the `<-` symbol to a string.

Comment: I think adding the `just for assignment` part for completeness, but overstep my role as observer.